# Problema em nova linha (SHIFT+ENTER)

Tags: suporte, status-intencional, edição, markdown

**Irei direto ao ponto:**

Vamos ao problema:
Aqui está o problema :(

**Veja a imagem para entender:**

<kbd>[image: Problema ao pular linha]</kbd>

Isto é extremamente irritante, principalmente dentro das `tags de código`.

A razão para o problema é inserir quebra de linha pressionando `SHIFT + ENTER`, ao invés de apenas `ENTER`.

**Existe alguma correção que possa fazer da minha parte (sem ser mudar o habito)?**
Quem quiser editar esta publicação pode verificar que  a quebra de linha existe, mas na publicação não é exibida.

Comment: Coloque dois espaços depois de `vamos ao problema ` que a linha será quebrada.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Essa pergunta foi respondida por [balpha](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/115866/balpha) no [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45617/why-should-users-have-to-press-return-twice-to-insert-new-lines/45635#45635) e se estivéssemos em qualquer Stack Exchange em Inglês essa pergunta seria marcada como duplicada. No entanto, para fins de tradução, resumirei o que o balpha disse lá no Meta aqui.

Esse comportamento não é um bug e foi criado intencionalmente para ser assim. Quebras de linhas e parágrafos são duas coisas distintas. Durante a leitura de um texto, seus olhos automaticamente vão para o início da próxima linha.

Já em uma quebra de parágrafo, você tem 2 opções: Identação (como feita no Word) ou uma linha em branco.

O conceito de linha em branco foi utilizado na comunidade Stack Exchange para copiar a forma como emails funcionam. Lá você geralmente não tem a opção de adicionar identação no início de um parágrafo para poder causar no leitor uma breve pausa na leitura. Além disso, você não sabe qual a resolução do monitor do leitor do texto, então *renderizações* de emails geralmente **ignoram** quebra de linhas simples para poder garantir que o leitor, independente do tamanho de seu monitor, possa ter a sensação de leitura do texto da forma como o autor desejou.

Quando você usa 2 enters em um email, independente da resolução do monitor, você causará ao leitor a sensação de parágrafo finalizado e, automaticamente, uma pausa na leitura é gerada. Já com 1 enter só, você não sabe como poderá ser o resultado.

Se mesmo assim você desejar inserir uma quebra de linha você mesmo,
é possível adicionar 2 espaços  e enter. Isso fará com que o renderizador ignore as regras anteriormente mencionadas e crie o texto exatamente como **você** deseja, sem levar em consideração o tamanho da tela do futuro leitor,
podendo gerar um texto desagradável de se ler.